# Ruby gem to track search engines redirection traffic (search keyworks)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-analytics, search-keywords

Most of the traffic from my site is sent by search engines. I am trying to track the keywords used on the search (EG to have real-time stats on the 'hottest' searches).

What are my options? I thought of:

1. Parsing the HTTP_REFERER (using a list regexps for major search engines)
2. Importing google analytics data (using [google analytics api](http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/home.html)) - however this is not realtime

Are there any gems/libraries that offer support for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write a middleware for rack to do this.  http://www.hokstad.com/slidingstats is an example of one that tracks referrers.  It is pretty easy to hack and not complicated so you can probably use this as a launchpad for what you want to do.